# Maximum and minimum of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

For complex numbers $z$ satisfying $|z-8-16i| = 2\sqrt{5}$, find the least possible value of $|z|$ and the greatest possible value of $|z|$.

First I let $z = x+iy$ and used this to write the equation in the form $(x-8)^2 +(y-16)^2 = 20$; then I solved for $y$ and took the first derivative and set it equal to $0$. I got the value of $x$ as $8$ and corresponding $y$ values as $16\pm 2\sqrt{5}$ then I used the second derivative test to determine the max and the min coordinate, then wrote them into Cartesian form as follows: $8+(16\pm 2\sqrt{5})i = z$ and finally found $|z|$. However, the answer for the problem is max = $10\sqrt{5}$ and min = $6\sqrt{5}$. How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a small mistake along the way.

Step 1: $y = 16 \pm \sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2}$

Step 2: objective function is $x^2 + y^2 = x^2 + (16 \pm \sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2})^2$

Step 3a: set derivative to $0$ for "+":
$$\frac{16 (16 - 2 x + \sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2})}{\sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2}} = 0$$
gives $x=10$ and $y=20$ and $|z|=10\sqrt{5}$

Step 3b: set derivative to $0$ for "-":
$$\frac{16 (-16 + 2 x + \sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2})}{\sqrt{20 - (x-8)^2}} = 0$$
gives $x=6$ and $y=12$ and $|z|=6\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Why can’t I take dy/dx?

Comment: dy/dx of what??

Comment: I mean y = 16+- sqrt(20-(x-8)^2)’s derivative

Comment: that would minimize/maximize $y$ but the question asked to minimize/maximize $|z|$

Answer (score 0):

$|z| \leq |z - 8-16i| + |8+16i| = 2\sqrt{5} + 8\sqrt{5} = 10\sqrt{5}$. Then verifying, let $x = 10, y = 20$ so that $|z-8-16i| = |2-4i| = \sqrt{20}$ as desired.